# Why is Xcode auto-completion so slow?

Tags: xcode

I'm working with the latest Xcode 11 on a SwiftUI project.
I opened a new question because all I found are a bit outdated.

I found Xcode auto-completion to be ridiculously slow on my 2016 15" MBP equipped with top-notch i7  (which is not under load by other processes) and 16GB RAM.

The file I'm working on has 50 lines or less.
The project is a simple one with 10 files or so.

Every time I type something it takes 3 seconds or so to start suggesting.

For comparison, Visual Studio 2017 on an older PC takes 1 second to autocomplete on a 1500-lines file loaded from a quite huge 50-projects solution.

I don't even want to image how Xcode would perform in a similar configuration...

Comment: So sad... By the way, I use ReSharper in VS and I feel fine with JetBrains product. Does AppCode already supports SwiftUI with live preview?

Comment: No currently not (from the issues I read), you have to do it in Xcode. For storyboards, swiftui and coredata model creator I use Xcode, the rest AppCode

Comment: Have you tried deleting module cache? Cache hint are stored here: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache

Comment: @christianmini not yet, but I don't see what could be cached, I don't quite use Xcode